# Removing duplicate row values and retain the rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have duplicate rows across the dataframe. I need to remove the duplicate row values and retain only one of them but keep the rows as such.

Trying with `duplicated`, `distinct` or `unique` does not allow me to retain the rows.

```
S.No   Rate   Proportion Control
C11    50     0.9         A
C11    50     0.9         B
C11    50     0.9         A
C21    40     0.8         B
C21    40     0.8         A
C21    40     0.8         A
```

```
S.No   Rate   Proportion Control
C11                       A
C11                       B
C11    50     0.9         A
C21                       B
C21                       A
C21    40     0.8         A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
df[duplicated(df[1:3], fromLast = TRUE),2:3] <- ''

df
#  S.No Rate Proportion Control
#1  C11                       A
#2  C11                       B
#3  C11   50        0.9       A
#4  C21                       B
#5  C21                       A
#6  C21   40        0.8       A
```

The equivalent in `dplyr` would be,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(2:3), funs(replace(., duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE), '')))
```

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan Why didn't you accept this answer? It was the first one posted and includes two ways of achieving what you needed.

Comment: I tried his code first and then yours. However, both of them deserves an acceptance. But , there is no chance to do it here.

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan It's not my code, my code is below. I just thought that this answer deserves the check mark more while respecting and acknowledging the contribution of the other poster.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, not clear about the conditions but you can try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(S.No) %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, ~replace(., row_number() != n(),''))
  #OR
  #mutate_at(vars(Rate,Proportion), ~replace(., row_number() != n(),''))

#  S.No  Rate  Proportion Control
# <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>  
#1 C11   ""    ""         A      
#2 C11   ""    ""         B      
#3 C11   50    0.9        A      
#4 C21   ""    ""         B      
#5 C21   ""    ""         A      
#6 C21   40    0.8        A
```

This replaces empty values for every entry in columns `Rate`  and `Proportion` except the last row in each group (`S.No`).

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(S.No = c("C11", "C11", "C11", "C21", "C21", "C21"
), Rate = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 40L, 40L), Proportion = c(0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8), Control = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. `dplyr` with `mutate_at` works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(S.No) %>% mutate_at(2:3, .funs = funs( . = case_when(
  n() != row_number() ~  "",
  TRUE ~ as.character(.)
)))
```